# How to call/use this module in other JS files/modules

Tags: javascript, function, design-patterns

I read some JS module design patterns recently. I came across this small code snippet as below.

```
(function(window) {
    var Module = {
        data: "I'm happy now!"
    };

    window.Module = Module;
})(window);
```

Still not quite understand this code well, my questions are:

- How to use/call this module outside this particluar JS file? Need I
  assign a variable to this module? e.g. var module1 = (...)(...);
- Could anyone explain what the window parameter here stands for?
- Is it a good practice to have two/three such kind of modules in the
  same file?

Comment: From my point of view this may be everything, but not a module design pattern.

Comment: @connexo in practice, it is a module design pattern as scoping the code into a function is a first steop to prevent accidental global scope pollution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main reason to create an anonymous function in this case is to prevent global object pollution. It's not really a module pattern.

The problem arise when you declare a variable. Without the function scope, the variable will be added to the global object (window). If you were to declare the variables within a function. It would add the variable to the function scope without polluting the global object window.

What happen is that a javascript file could add a variable named `foo` and on a different file use that variable named `foo` too. Unless you really want to have a variable shared by two javascript files, it would probably create conflicts and bug that are difficult to fix.

For example: a.js

```
var foo = "one"
```

b.js

```
var foo = "two"
```

c.js

```
alert(foo)
```

In this case, the alert box might show either "one" or "two", depending of the order in the javascript files are included.

But having this a.js:

```
(function () {
    var foo = "one"
})()
```

b.js

```
(function () {
    var foo = "two"
})()
```

c.js

```
(function () {
    alert(foo)
})()
```

This would create an error as you cannot `alert` a non declared variable.

One way to detect undefined variables, is to make sure to execute the javascript code in **strict mode**.

To do that, add the string `"use strict"` at the top of the file or function.

```
function () {
  "use strict"
  ...
}
```

Undeclared variable will raise errors and it should be possible to fix the code that way.

Also, if you forget to declare a variable with the `var` keyword, it might end up adding the variable to the global scope even if the code is scoped into a function. The only way to prevent global scope pollution is to run the code in strict mode.

In the code snippet that you provided, the module with name Module is explicitly added to the window object. You can access the window object from any place in javascript unless the window name is ghosted by an other variable.

Now, back to the modules. If you want to define *modules*, it can be done in many ways. As an exemple, you could create an object on the window object called modules. In this object, you'll insert your modules.

module.js

```
window.modules = {}
```

foo.js

```
(function (window) {
  var module = {}
  ...
  window.modules.foo = module
})(window)
```

This variant isn't super good as you have to manually add the module to the `modules` object. You have to manually modify the window object, and that can be subject to errors.

modules.js

```
window.modules = {}

function define(name, constructor) {
  var module = {exports: {}}
  constructor(module)
  window.modules[name] = module.exports
}

function require(name) {
  return window.modules[name]
}
```

foo.js

```
define("foo", function (module) {
  module.exports.one = function () {
    return 1
  }

  module.exports.plus = function (a, b) {
    return a + b
  }
})
```

bar.js

```
define("bar", function (module) {
  module.exports = function () {
    var foo = require("foo")
    return foo.plus(foo.one(), foo.one())
  }
})
```

This is a module definition that looks a bit like module defined with http://requirejs.org/. It is quite basic as it doesn't take into account module dependencies so if `bar` is loaded and used before `foo`. Then the `require` method won't be able to return the module.

Also, if you want to store modules without having them visible into the global scope, you can only define the `require` and `define` method on the window object and hide modules into an anonymous scope like this:

```
  (function (window) {
    var modules = {}

    function define(name, constructor) {
      var module = {exports: {}}
      constructor(module)
      modules[name] = module.exports
    }

    function require(name) {
      return modules[name]
    }

    window.define = define
    window.require = require
  })(window)
```

This way, `define` and `require` are the only function that can give you access to modules. Other modules won't be able to modify other modules without requiring them first. This can be useful when using third parties script that could conflict with your module system.

Comment: Your answer is really helpful for me to understand how to avoid global variables pollution. In order to make the example more completed, can you also add some code on how to expose foo from either a.js or b.js, such that c.js can access foo. I believe it will also be more useful for other readers/js newbies to understand this topic. Thanks.

Comment: @catlovespurple there

Comment: very helpful. great resource! I granted it as correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @catlovespurple Thank you

Comment: very helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact this is not a module, but a *Self-Invoking Ananymous function* or an *Immediate function* which gets an object in parameter and assign a `Module` property to it:

- The page `window` is a parameter passed to this function.
- So an object named `Module` containing a `data` property is assigned to window.

**JavaScript Self-Invoking Functions:**

> A self-invoking expression is invoked (started) automatically, without being called.
>
> Function expressions will execute automatically if the expression is
>   followed by `()`.
>
> You cannot self-invoke a function declaration.
>
> You have to add parentheses around the function to indicate that it is
>   a function expression

So As you can see Immediate Functions can't be called as its name states it will be immediately executed and by its self, no other function or scope can execute it.

For better reference take a look at :

- **[Javascript Self Invoking Functions](https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/)**.
- **[*Self-Invoking Functions* section in JavaScript Function Definitions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp)**.

---

And concerning your last question about its benefits and good practices as shown on the given [Article reference](https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/):

**Where to use self-executing functions?**

> One obvious situation is when you want to auto-run a function like I
>   showed in above example but that is trivial. If you are in a situation
>   where you want to run a piece of code repeatedly like updating
>   something in the database based on user interaction or fetching
>   records from database every 10 seconds or you want to load new stories
>   via `ajax` similar to how facebook does on its homepage or some other
>   similar situation, one would normally go for `setInterval` function
>   something like this:

```
setInterval(doStuff, 10000);
```

> Above, `doStuff` function will get called every 10 seconds. That is the
>   normal approach most developers seem to go with. However, there is a
>   huge problem with that.
>
> The `setInterval` will call doStuff function exactly at specified time of 10 seconds again and again irrespective
>   of whether doStuff function actually finished doing what it is
>   supposed to do. That is bad and will certainly get you into unexpected
>   results.
>
> That is one example of where `setInterval` is "bad" and should be
>   avoided.
>
> This is exactly where *self-executing functions* come in handy. We can
>   do the same task with the help of *self-executing function* along with
>   `setTimeout` like this:

```
function foo(){
     // your other code here  
     setTimeout(foo, 10000);
}();
```

> This code will also repeat itself again and again with one difference.
>   `setTimeout` will never get triggered unless `doStuff` is finished. A much
>   better approach than using `setInterval` in this situation.

**Calling it from another file:**

And if this function is on another file it will be called automatically if this file is included.

**Why do we use Self-Invoking Functions in JavaScript?**

And if you ask yourself why do we use these functions, self-invoked function are used to manage **[Variable Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx)**.

Take a look at the **[answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17058668/3669624)** for further information.

Comment: Thanks chsdk! Can you please also show me how to use this anonymous function outside this JS file?

Comment: @catlovespurple Take a look at my Edited answer you will find all the explanation you are looking for  and all the answers to your questions.